# How to get the error message in try() with rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

When I use `rmarkdown::render` to compile the following code into html,

````
```{r, error=T}
setClass('A', slots=c())
try(setClass('A', slots=c()))
```
````

I found that there is no error message shown in the html file for the second command, instead it is printed in the command line. Does anybody know to make the error message printed in the html file as well? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

here are 2 methods to print the error message

````
```{r, error=T}
setClass('A', slots=c())

#method 1
temp <- try(setClass('A', slots=c()))
message(temp)

#method 2
try(setClass('A', slots=c()))
message(geterrmessage())
```
````

found the 2 methods from Details section in `?try`

> try evaluates an expression and traps any errors that occur during the
>   evaluation. If an error occurs then the error message is printed to
>   the stderr connection unless options("show.error.messages") is false
>   or the call includes silent = TRUE. The error message is also stored
>   in a buffer where it can be retrieved by geterrmessage. (This should
>   not be needed as the value returned in case of an error contains the
>   error message.)